# Write non-SQL dataset to SQL table in DataIku

Tags: dataiku

I dont seem to find a way to write the output from a previous step in the flow into a SQL table, using the SQL recipes.  When I read the documentation, it seems both types of SQL action can only take as an input a SQL dataset?  This cant be write, as you would imagine you would want to create datasets in the flow and then commit them to a database?

https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/code_recipes/sql.html

In the docs above, it describes In\Out parameters as needing to be SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it doesn't seem possible with a SQL recipe which executes fully in the database.

That being said you can probably use a sync recipe to put your non-SQL dataset in your SQL db so that you can execute a SQL recipe.